# Is it possible .net framework 4.0 consume oauth2 bearer token

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, owin

My authentication server is built using .NET Framework 4.6.1/Web API 2.
Basically the standard way of building the ASP.NET Identity 2.0 using OWIN/KATANA setup in WEB API 2.

The question is, my company has a legacy system that is running .NET framework 4.0.
I need a way for this legacy system to consume the bearer token and find out whether the access token is valid/invalid using the [Authorize] method.

Is it possible to use .NET framework 4.0 as my Resource Server provided it knows the MachineKey?

Comment: What's the challenge you are facing? Authorize attribute was added long back

Comment: @NitinSingh chanllenge faced was the method it authorize. The normal way was going to use OWIN self-host way check by same machine key value to determine the validity of the bearer token. Right now the legacy system cannot install dependencies and is running on ASMX .net framework 4.0.